# How do I add new type-safe accessors to a Gradle Project?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

We have a plugin which defines additional properties and adds them as extension properties, like:

```kotlin
project.extra["copyright"] = "Copyright ..."
```

Then in the build scripts, I can access this like:

```kotlin
project.extra["copyright"]
```

I'd like to just write:

```kotlin
project.copyright
```

Some Gradle plugins seem to do something like this. I can access `project.sourceSets` or `project.kotlin` even though those certainly aren't in the `Project` interface.

Using an IDE, I can drill into those convenience methods, which then lands me in some autogenerated code, so I know it's being autogenerated *somewhere*, but I haven't been able to find any clues to how to get this to happen for our own plugin. The Gradle docs [mention type-safe accessors](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors) which is ultimately what allowed me to phrase the question, but the docs don't say how to add new ones.

How do we get this treatment for our own plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Creating DSL-like APIS is documented here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#modeling_dsl_like_apis.

It's pretty easy to do. Here's a quick guide, and some tips.

1. Define an extension.

   ```kotlin
   import org.gradle.api.provider.Property

   interface MyExtension {
     val copyright: Property<String>
   }
   ```

   It looks pretty boring! What's important is that it's either be an abstract class, or an interface - this is so Gradle can create a new instance (see ['Managed types'](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_gradle_types.html#managed_types)), and this is where the Gradle magic begins.

   > Aside: I've used `Property<String>` instead of `String`, although both will work. I recommend using types compatible with [Lazy Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html).
2. Register the extension.

   ```
   import org.gradle.api.*

   abstract class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

     override fun apply(project: Project) {

       val myExtension: MyExtension = 
           project.extensions.create("myPlugin", MyExtension::class.java)
     }
   }
   ```

   This is the magic part. Simply by registering the extension against the project, Gradle will make the extension available and automatically generate Kotlin-DSL convenience methods.
3. Apply the plugin

   ```kotlin
   // build.gradle.kts

   plugins {
     id("my-plugin")
   }

   myPlugin {
     copyright.set("blah blah 2022")
   }
   ```

   Just like that, Gradle will generate Kotlin DSL accessors. Here's one of them:

   ```kotlin
   // Accessorsajp3oxzka99ro52ctxwv0petb.kt

   /**
    * Configures the [myPlugin][MyExtension] extension.
    */
   fun org.gradle.api.Project.`myPlugin`(configure: Action<MyExtension>): Unit =
       (this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions.configure("myPlugin", configure)
   ```
4. Use the extension values

   Going back to the Plugin definition, lets say you want to register your own task:

   ```kotlin
   // a demo task
   abstract class MyTask : DefaultTask() {
     @get:Input
     abstract val copyright: Property<String>

     @TaskAction
     fun run() {
       println("Copyright is ${copyright.get()}")
     }
   }
   ```

   (Note that this task, like the extension, is a 'managed type').

   Now the custom task can be registered, and a default value for `copyright` set.

   ```kotlin
   abstract class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

     override fun apply(project: Project) {

       val myExtension: MyExtension = project.extensions.create("myPlugin", MyExtension::class.java)

       project.tasks.register("myCustomTask", MyTask::class.java) {
         copyright.set(myExtension.copyright)
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   It's good that both `MyExtension` and `MyTask` use `Property<String>` - the actual value will be evaluated lazily, and only if required.

   Now if I run `./gradlew :myCustomTask`, I see:

   ```
   > Task :myCustomTask
   Copyright is blah blah 2022
   ```

##### Further reading

- What if you want to have multiple copyrights? Then you can create a [configuration container](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#declaring_a_dsl_configuration_container)
- What if `MyExtension` has *lots* of properties and you want to provide them *all* to `MyTask`? Then you can use [`@Nested` inputs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_input_nested_inputs)
- The extension properties can [have default values](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#applying_conventions).

Comment: `Aside: I've used Property<String> instead of String, although both will work. I recommend using types compatible with Lazy Configuration`; For people who wonder why this is recommended, @wakingrufus explains that this is because `using a property allows you to avoid race conditions with afterEvaluate clauses. Extension values set by build scripts are NOT available at configuration time`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73480158/741217

Comment: I believe this answer should accepted, great explanation. Thank you !