# Gradle Extensions: can plain Kotlin types be used instead of Property<T> for properties with simple values?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The [Gradle docs for lazy configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html) states that in extension/DSL classes, properties like `var someProperty = "default value"` should actually be `val someProperty: Property<String> = objectFactory.property(String::class.java).convention("default value")`. This is to avoid unnecessary computation during the configuration phase;

I wonder if there is any downside in using plain types for simple values. The benefits are clear to me in case of computation or I/O, but if anything, for simple values I’d say a plain type would result in slightly less resource use during configuration (one less object created and no method calls).

The main reasons I prefer plain property types for simple values is simplicity and especially that the assignment operator can be used in a build script with Kotlin DSL, e.g. `someProperty = "foo"`. I find this cleaner than `someProperty.set("foo")` and the latter is also imperative, while Gradle DSLs are otherwise mostly declarative.

It seems to work fine and in the task there would still be a `Property<String>` counterpart that can be initialized with `someProperty.set(extension.someProperty)`, but since the documentation doesn’t mention it as a possibility for simple values, I’m wondering if there is a good reason for it that I couldn’t think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to avoiding unnecessary computation during the configuration phase, using a property allows you to avoid race conditions with afterEvaluate clauses. Extension values set by build scripts are NOT available at configuration time.

Therefore, your example of `task.someProperty.set(extension.somePlainField)` will not work.

Using `task.someProperty.set(extension.someProperty)` (the method with signature `set(value: Provider<T>)`) makes sure that `extension.someProperty.get()` is not invoked until the task executes and reads its Property.

in order to achieve your goal of a fluent extension api, the recommended approach is to add a method to your extension such as

```kotlin
fun someProperty(value: String) {
  someProperty.set(value)
}
```

then, build scripts can use it like:

```kotlin
myExtension {
  someProperty("my value")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and that DSL syntax is even better in IMO. Does the recommendation to use `Property` also apply to settings plugins or are plain properties the way to go there, since this comes before the configuration phase and there are no tasks?

Comment: I usually use project properties (gradle.properties) for configuration phase settings